# IE ignores added onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

The  Jquery code below works ok with firefox, Safari, Opera but not with IE. I kinda know why this isn't working in IE after reading a lot about it but I do not know how to fix it. 
My understanding (I think) is that this method will assign a attribute of "onclick" in IE rather than an event method. Therefore it will not fire in IE and the href fires instead which in this case is "#" which is exactly what is happening. What is the correct way of adding the onclick event. There is more javascript code below the code shown but I do not think it's relevant to the question.

```
<a id="product_photo_zoom_url" href="/PhotoGallery.asp?ProductCode=9857%2D116%2D003"  
title="9857-116-003 Ignition box"><img id="product_photo" 
src="/v/vspfiles/photos/9857-116-003-2T.jpg" border="0"
alt="9857-116-003 Ignition box" /></a> <br /><a id="product_photo_zoom_url2"  href="/PhotoGallery.asp?ProductCode=9857%2D116%2D003"
title="9857-116-003 Ignition box">
<img src="/v/vspfiles/templates/100/images/buttons/btn_largerphoto.gif" border="0"></a>





var global_URL_Encode_Current_ProductCode;
var global_Config_ProductPhotosFolder;
var global_Current_ProductCode;

var titleattr = $("a#product_photo_zoom_url").attr("title"); 
var picurl='tb_show(titleattr, \'/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDESC=N&ProductCode=\' + global_URL_Encode_Current_ProductCode + \'&TB_iframe=true&height=600&width=520\');return false;'

$("a#product_photo_zoom_url").attr('onclick', picurl);
$("a#product_photo_zoom_url").attr('href', '#');

$("a#product_photo_zoom_url2").attr('onclick', picurl);
$("a#product_photo_zoom_url2").attr('href', '#');
```

Comment: well I am a nub which is why I am here, thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function picurl()
{
  tb_show(titleattr, '/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDESC=N&ProductCode=' 
 + global_URL_Encode_Current_ProductCode 
 + '&TB_iframe=true&height=600&width=520');  
  return false;
} 

$("a#product_photo_zoom_url").click(picurl);
```

You can get rid of the `var picurl = ...`.  Note that `picurl` is now a function, rather than a string of code.

Comment: I choose to use this method because I can call the picurl function at will. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You are using jQuery, there's no reason why not to use it's cross-browser event handling abstraction:

```
//...
$("a#product_photo_zoom_url").click(function () {
  tb_show(titleattr, '/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDESC=N&ProductCode=' +
                     global_URL_Encode_Current_ProductCode + 
                    '&TB_iframe=true&height=600&width=520');
  return false;
});
//...
```

Note that we are using a function, not a string as the event handler.

Give a look to:

- [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: This functionally worked as well but the other one seemed to fit a little better. Thanks for the lesson!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$("a#product_photo_zoom_url").click(picurl);
```

Make sure that you wrap your code in `ready` handler. Sot it should be like:

```
$(function(){
  $("a#product_photo_zoom_url").click(picurl});
});
```

Comment: That syntax doesn't really make sense.  It won't work regardless of whether picurl is a function or a string (like in the OP).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: You are right, i forgot i was already dealing with a function, updated.